# How to render different Layouts in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to show different Layouts using React. I have Navbar with links. For every links (Service, Works, Contact...etc) I want to render Navbar, but for SignIn link I don't want to show it. So my code is following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import PublicLayout from './components/layouts/PublicLayout';
import SigninLayout from './components/layouts/SigninLayout';
import Main from './components/pages/Main';
import Services from './components/pages/Services';
import Price from './components/pages/Price';
import Works from './components/pages/Works';
import Signin from './components/pages/Signin';
import NotFound from './components/pages/NotFound';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="App">
                    <Switch>
                        <PublicLayout>
                            <Route exact path='/' component={Main} />
                            <Route exact path='/services' component={Services} />
                            <Route exact path='/prices' component={Price} />
                            <Route exact path='/works' component={Works} />
                        </PublicLayout>
                        <SigninLayout>
                            <Route exact path='/signin' component={Signin} />
                        </SigninLayout>
                        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I expect that SigninLayout should use for SignIn url. But I still see Navbar instead. This is my SigninLayout code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SigninLayout extends Component {
    state = {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.props.children }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SigninLayout;
```

And this is my SignIn component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Signin extends Component {
    state = {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Войти</h1>
                <form>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="укажите e-mail" />
                    <input type="text" placeholder="укажите пароль" />
                    <button>Войти</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Signin;
```

Why the Navbar is showing? What I'm doing wrong?

**UPD:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from '../nav/Navbar';

class PublicLayout extends Component {
    state = {
        items: [
            { id: 1, name: 'Услуги', link: '/services' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Цены', link: '/prices' },
            { id: 3, name: 'Как это работает?', link: '/works' },
            { id: 4, name: 'Войти', link: '/signin' },
        ]
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar items={ this.state.items } />
                { this.props.children }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PublicLayout;
```

Comment: I don't see how `PublicLayout` looks like but if navbar is there then it will be rendered, regardless what its children are and which routes you put there (`Route` should be an outer component). If that's the case then use `Switch` (for example) to apply one or the other (I'd suggest to always use `Switch` to slightly speed-up things when routes are mutually exclusive)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti but I'm using switch. And yes - navbar is in PublicLayout. I expect to show it. But Navbar isn't in SigninLayout. It should not appear for signin url. Isn't it?

Comment: I see but it's in the wrong place, it won't _switch_ its parent. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let's use `<Switch>`, no need to evaluate any other route if you already found your one:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="App">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/signin' component={SigninLayout} />
                        <Route component={PublicLayout} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

Note that we're selecting between two layouts here, sub-routes will go there. This was your error: an outer component (`PublicLayout` and `SigningLayout`) will be rendered even if none of its children are visible (well...unless it's empty itself).

```
const PublicLayout = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Main} />
        <Route exact path='/services' component={Services} />
        <Route exact path='/prices' component={Price} />
        <Route exact path='/works' component={Works} />
    </Switch>
);
```

Parallel with `SigningLayout` should be easy. Of course that's just an example but should be trivial to (untested):

```
const App = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/signin'>
                    <SigningLayout><SignIn /></SigningLayout>
                </Route>
                <Route>
                    <PublicLayout>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route exact path='/' component={Main} />
                            <Route exact path='/services' component={Services} />
                            <Route exact path='/prices' component={Price} />
                            <Route exact path='/works' component={Works} />
                        </Switch>
                    <PublicLayout>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: I can't understand how I have to modify my PublicLayout file? Can you give a full code for PublicLayout?

Comment: @Nastro you do not need to modify it, it's just an example. `Route` component has other useful ways to render its content, see updated example.

Comment: I updated my question and added PublicLayout code. Maybe you can look at and give me more details? really need to understand it.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Nastro see updated answer. Side question: it's often a matter of personal taste but I don't _feel_ that those items are really part of the state (as they seem to be immutable, unless it's just a simplification to post it here). Anyway, it's not that important because it's a common practice I saw pretty often and I heard pretty convincing arguments for both sides ;)

Comment: Thank you @Adriano Repetti now it's working as I planned! Need to read about Route. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a bit restructuring of Switch

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="App">
                    <Switch>
                        <SigninLayout>
                            <Route exact path='/signin' component={Signin} />
                        </SigninLayout>
                        <PublicLayout>
                            <Route exact path='/' component={Main} />
                            <Route exact path='/services' component={Services} />
                            <Route exact path='/prices' component={Price} />
                            <Route exact path='/works' component={Works} />
                        </PublicLayout>
                        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I really don't know why. It happened to me once, I did this and it worked. I think that Switch gives priority in rendering paths to top components. that is why it is good that you put Route with path='*'  at bottom